# Colors persist after leaving vim, how to fix?

Tags: macos, vim

My terminal is just default black text and white background but when I enter vim and then exit the black background of my vim color scheme persists only on the lines I've entered since leaving vim.

```
$ vim README.md // normal terminal colors

... // whitespace until the end of the terminal window

$   // this line and every line I enter below is black
```

I resort to typing reset to fix this. Any ideas how to stop this from happening?

Comment: What is `$TERM` set to in this terminal?

Comment: xterm-256color, this happens both in osx terminal and iterm2

Comment: Vim *should* be reading the terminal description and resetting colors before it exits.  The terminal description (you can check with `infocmp`) contains the `op` capability which tells it how.  The likely place to look would be a problem with the color-scheme (doing something that vim does not expect).